# Choose which binary is default binary on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: linux, mac, terminal, shell, homebrew

I have installed the latest SVN 1.8 via homebrew on my Mac. However now If I run `svn --version` I get back that I have 1.7. Next thinng I run `which -a svn` which then shows me I have it twice:

```
/usr/bin/svn
/usr/local/bin/svn
```

If I run `/usr/local/bin/svn --version` I get back 1.8

How do I now tell my MAC that the default binary to use is `/usr/local/bin/svn` and not `/usr/bin/svn`?

Comment: By deleteing /usr/bin/svn? ;)

Comment: I am not sure if this is a smart idea, since this comes with Xcode and I don't know if I will face some issues with that. Is the binary that is the default arbitrary? I can't imagine, it has to be defined somewhere, just where?

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic link is the solution, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198782/svn-use-from-default-path-usr-bin-instead-of-opt-local-bin

You already have svn in two locations:

```
   /usr/bin/svn
   /usr/local/bin/svn
```

If you create symbolic links for svn in /usr/local/bin with the same name, it will effectively remove the binaries from the macport.

or else you have to create symbolic link with different name which is not very useful.

How about having an alias that points to the one you want to use:

```
 alias svn=/usr/bin/svn
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your PATH variable.  Put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` and possibly before many other dir's, as this allows anything you have specifically compiled/installed to override the system defaults.  Obviously, take care that you know what's in `/usr/local/bin` first, but it sounds like you do.